# When using python tvm, No CUDA-capable device is detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, cuda, nvidia

I wrote the following python code

```py
import tvm

ctx = tvm.device("cuda", 0)
print("ctx: ", ctx.exist)
```

The output is

```
ctx:  False
```

However, I install cuda and cuda driver.
The `nvidia-smi` result is,

```
NVIDIA-SMI 495.44       Driver Version: 495.44       CUDA Version: 11.5
```

I use `lspci -vnn | grep VGA` to check whether there is a GPU. The result is

```
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. Integrated Matrox G200eW3 Graphics Controller [102b:0536] (rev 04) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
3b:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1e04] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
af:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1e04] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
d8:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1e04] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

And my system is `Linux PowerEdge-R740 5.4.0-90-generic #101~18.04.1-Ubuntu`.My python version is 3.6.

I don't know why tvm cannot find the correct device.

Comment: This probably a mismatch between whatever CUDA version tvm requires (whatever tvm is) and the version of CUDA you have chosen to install. They must match. This is not a CUDA programming question, per se

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible source of error could be that you did not enable CUDA backend support when installing TVM.

> Edit build/config.cmake to customize the compilation options.
> Change set(USE_CUDA OFF) to set(USE_CUDA ON) to enable CUDA backend. Do the same for other backends and libraries you want to build for (OpenCL, RCOM, METAL, VULKAN, …).

Please refer to: https://tvm.apache.org/docs/install/from_source.html#install-from-source

(I would have commented, but not enough reputation)